# MENU DISPLAY PROBLEMS

Tags: css, menu

So I have a menu from ul and li, and it looks something like this at page load:
[image]

but when i click each menu and executed the code this happens:

[image]

what should i do? here's my CSS:

```
#menu-centered {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#menu-centered ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 99px;
    width: 603px;
}
#menu-centered li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(images/menu1.png) no-repeat right top;
}
#menu-centered a {
    border-style: none;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-width: medium;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 20px 30px 0px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 68px;
    width: 130px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu-centered a:hover {
    background: url(images/menu2.png) no-repeat right top;
}
```

and here's my html code for the menus:

```
<div id="menu-centered">
<ul>
<li> <a href="javascript:Clikbtn1()" >MENU1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:Clikbtn2()">MENU2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:Clikbtn3()">MENU3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Does the menu look right just when you load it? Also, you're running various JavaScript functions you have not included.

Answer (score 0):

Your menus need some LoVe and HAte. In other words you need to create all four of the important link pseudoselectors to avoid letting browsers destroy your layout by applying the default active pseudoslector.

Define a:link, a:visited, a:hover and a:active for your menu, in that order exactly.

Comment: Solved it? turns out i use response.writeline to execute my javascript codes. that's why. thanks all anyways, youre all great!